# UIPageViewController not completing transition on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` that handles an array of `viewControllers`
when I swipe between them everything is fine, But I have a few methods (after successful login and after menu button click) that trigger a 'jump' to a `viewController` in the `UIPageViewControllers` array.
whenever I jump to a page, the transition isn't complete and I have a screen that is 'stuck' between two `viewControllers`

For simplicity, I will only add the successful login code, because I set everything the same for button clicks, and the same thing happens.

This is my UIPageViewController setup:

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource , UIPageViewControllerDelegate , ClubViewControllerDelegate , CustomSvDelegate{

//clubvcdelegate protocol method

func fbLoggedInWithSuccess(){
self.displayPageForIndex(index: 4, animated: false)
}

//menubuttondelegate protocol method
func menuButtonPressed0() {

    self.displayPageForIndex(index: 0, animated: false)
    self.currentPageIndex = 0
    self.closeMenu()
}

//page swipe control

lazy var vcArray : [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.vcInstance (name : "clubVC"),
            self.vcInstance (name : "menuVC"),
            self.vcInstance (name : "contactVC"),
            self.vcInstance (name : "aboutVC"),
            self.vcInstance (name : "membersVC")]
    }()

private func vcInstance(name : String) -> UIViewController{
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    return storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    if let clubVC = vcArray.first {
        let club = clubVC as! ClubViewController
        club.delegate = self
        setViewControllers([clubVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    self.generateStackView()
}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds} else if view is UIPageControl {view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear}
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = vcArray.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {return vcArray.last}

    guard vcArray.count > previousIndex else {return nil}

    return vcArray[previousIndex]

}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = vcArray.index(of: viewController) else {return nil}

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

    guard nextIndex < vcArray.count else {return vcArray.first}

    guard vcArray.count > nextIndex else {return nil}

    return vcArray[nextIndex]

}

public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{
    return vcArray.count
}


public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{
    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first ,
    let firstViewControllerIndex = vcArray.index(of: firstViewController) else {
        return 0
    }
    return firstViewControllerIndex
}
```

and this is how I set up things where fblogin is successful:

```
protocol ClubViewControllerDelegate:class {
func fbLoggedInWithSuccess()
}

class ClubViewController: UIViewController , FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
var delegate:ClubViewControllerDelegate?

func showFbDetails(){

    let accesToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()

    guard let accesTokenString = accesToken?.tokenString else {return}

    let credentials = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accesTokenString)

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("something went wrong" , error!)
            return
        }
        print ("succes")
        self.delegate?.fbLoggedInWithSuccess()
    })

}
```

Pictures:
[image]
[image]

**EDIT2**
This only happens when animated it true, when false it completes correctly

**EDIT3**
This is the method I now use to set view controllers :

```
    func displayPageForIndex(index : Int , animated : Bool = true){
    assert(index >= 0 && index < self.vcArray.count, "Error: Attempting to display a page for an out of bounds index")
    if self.currentPageIndex == index {return}
    if index < self.currentPageIndex {
        self.setViewControllers([self.vcArray[index]], direction: .reverse, animated: false, completion: nil)
    } else if index > self.currentPageIndex {
        self.setViewControllers([self.vcArray[index]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I call it inside of `fbLoggenInWithSuccess` and `menuButtonPressed`.
Also, have a variable CurrentIndex that holds the current index of the page

Comment: Explain the purpose of your code, please. Why do you call `setViewControllers` twice? What is the weak self `pvcw` for? What is the `async` for?

Comment: I am no longer using that actually. But what i am trying to do is jump to a new viewController when login is successful/after button click. As I understand setviewcontrollers is my only way to change the current viewController @matt

Comment: Correct but the code you showed is very strange and I'm wondering why you're doing it and whether it might be causing the problem. I can only go on the code you say you're using, and you say that's the code you're using. Were you just lying when you said that? If so, why? Show your _real_ code if that's not the real code. Impossible to reproduce the issue or guess at its cause without knowing the real code.

Comment: this is the code i am using. the method i described in first edit is a fix i tried based on some online research but either i read wrong or it did not work. either way i posted what i am doing now. no lying here , eager to learn! @matt

Comment: Okay, but now I don't see any code that _calls_ your `displayPageForIndex` so I don't see what it has to do with all the other stuff you showed earlier. Your code just doesn't hang together, and you're not providing enough info to allow the problem to be reproduced.

Comment: as i said in the last edit: i have `displayPageForIndex` called from inside `func fbLoggedInWithSuccess` and  `func menuButtonPressed0`. now this is the the only code that is being called from those methods. i've edited the previous code so it is more clear(two top most methods). @matt

Comment: You have `self.delegate?.fbLoggedInWithSuccess()`. Does it help if you replace this with `DispatchQueue.main.async {self.delegate?.fbLoggedInWithSuccess()}` ?

Comment: sadly it does not

Comment: OK, well, you still haven't provided enough information to reproduce the problem. How is `showFbDetails` called?

Comment: Also you are doing many other strange things I could be asking about. Why are you keeping an array of view controllers? The whole point of a UIPageViewController is that you _don't_ do that. Also, are you aware that your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called repeatedly over the lifetime of the app? This could actually be interfering with things.

Comment: i was not aware of that! this solves the problem you are the man!

Comment: @GiladSchickler what are you currently using? I have a similar problem, but I don't use viewDidLayoutSubviews...

Answer (score 0):

As matt suggested removing `viewDidLayoutSubviews` resolved the issue

Comment: Glad that you found it! The usual thing is to put a property flag so that your customization code is performed just the first time the subviews are laid out and then never again. — My criticism about the array of view controllers still stands. This is wrong behavior.